# Will having the door light on all the time hurt the battery? Is it easy to fix on suzuki xl7?

Tags: lights, sensor, door

I have a 2003 suzuki xl7 that I've been running for 10 years. The door sensor is wacky now and is on almost all the time. It reacts when I'm driving and when I park is always on.

I've tried to get some basic info about this- I haven't yet done it but I could check on the individual door sensors (I think?) In any case, I assume I could do something to fix the sensor problems but haven't looked into it much yet.

In the meantime, I'm just wondering- will it be bad for the car or the battery if the light is on all the time? I can't imagine that it takes that much energy but you never know. Would it be bad if I never did anything about it?

Comment: Have you considered taking the bulb out?

Comment: I'm going to disagree with both answers here. You *will* damage the battery if you let this go, even if you deliberately drive every single day.  If you go with removing bulbs be sure you get all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on how often you drive it - every day may continue to be ok - as long as the battery gets a good charge but if you only run it once a week then no.

You have 3 possibilities:

1) remove the bulb - but obviously no light ...

2) remove the fuse - but this could stop other things working : clock, radio etc

3) fix / replace the damaged or broken switch...

I would do 1 as a temporary solution while sorting 3.

Answer (score 0):

Having the door light on continuously may not hurt the battery significantly, as mentioned elsewhere, but there could be another effect.

I had a similar switch fault on my VW and noticed that the interior light housing became excessively hot.  It was too hot to touch.  The interior light housing also contained the rain sensor for the auto-wipers and light sensor for the auto-headlights so I feared a fire.

Fortunately, just switching the interior light completely off solved the temperature issue until I had time to trace the fault.

I would recommend checking the temperature of your housing just in case.